# What is meant by " in capital spirits"?

Tags: meaning

There was once a dreadfully wicked hobgoblin. One day he was in capital spirits because he had made a looking glass which reflected everything that was good and beautiful in such a way that it dwindled almost to nothing, but anything that was bad and ugly stood out very clearly and looked much worse.
 This story is https://www.storynory.com/the-snow-queen-part-1/

Comment: Is it [capital³](https://www.lexico.com/definition/capital) or [spirits²](https://www.lexico.com/definition/spirit) that is causing the difficulty, or how the adjective is applied to the noun? The usage is dated.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not necessarily dated, but certainly uncommon in American English. You'll still hear this in Britain (depending on where you are in Britain, of course)

Comment: The 'excellent' meaning is in Merriam-Webster without any 'dated' note, but I agree it is somewhat old fashioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### He was feeling happy, good, or cheerful

**"He was in capital spirits"** = **"he was feeling happy"**

In British English, capital means "good, fine, excellent"

**"Spirits"** in this case means **"mood"** -> **"he was in poor spirits"** = **"he was sad"**

You could literally translate this to mean **"he was in an excellent mood"**